# Qual melhor forma de deixar um valor em sessão?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Qual melhor forma de deixar um valor em sessão no asp.net mvc ?

Esse valor, pode ser mudado pelo o usuário, quando ele quer, mas conforme vai usando o sistema, irá o usar o valor dessa sessão...

Por exemplo:

Setar um Paciente, então, conforme for navegando no sistema, as informações que ele for acessando, será daquele paciente, e não de outros.

Qual melhor forma de fazer isso? Session? static em um controller base?

Comment: Se possível dê mais informações, exemplo, quais dados você quer armazenar e para que?

Comment: Olá @Renan, editei com um exemplo, não sei se ficou claro

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o objeto ***[session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)*** para armazenar as informações do paciente.

O objeto Session permite que o desenvolvedor obtenha os dados, previamente persistidos na sessão, por tempo determinado (configurável, mas o padrão são 20 minutos). Mas, utilize este recurso com moderação, armazenando somente os dados necessários, uma vez que os dados da session são armazenados por padrão em memória, muitos dados podem desencadear problemas de escalabilidade.

Armazenando informações do paciente na session:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Paciente paciente = new Paciente
    {
        ID = 1,
        Nome = "Fulado"
    };

    Session["Paciente"] = paciente;
    return RedirectToAction("Navegar");
}
```

Obtendo os dados da session e reutilizando:

```
public ActionResult Navegar()
{
    Paciente paciente = Session["Paciente"] as Paciente;    
    return View(paciente);
}
```

Acessando dados na view com Razor:

```
@{ var pacienteDaSession = Session["paciente"]; }
```

Você perde as informações da session quando por exemplo a aplicação é reiniciada (exemplo: o arquivo Global.asax ou o Web.Config é modificado);

Acredito que não existe uma melhor maneira, mas, sim uma maneira mais organizada.

Exemplos:

Usando propriedades dentro do Controller:

```
public class MeuController : Controller
{
    public Paciente Paciente
    {
        get
        {
            return (Paciente)Session["Paciente"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["Paciente"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usando propriedades dentro de uma classe estatica:

```
public static class SessionContext
{    
        public static Paciente Paciente
        {
            get 
            {
                return (Paciente)HttpContext.Current.Session["Paciente"];
            }
            set 
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Paciente"] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Pode acontecer da Sessão se perder? Poderia ser usada para navegar entre todos os controllers/áreas ?

Comment: Você perde as informações da session quando por exemplo quando a aplicação é reiniciada (exemplo: o arquivo Global.asax ou o Web.Config é modificado). Sim, a informação da session pode ser acessada entre controllers/áreas.